# Dúvida - Condição Query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

Galera, na consulta abaixo está trazendo da seguinte forma. Porém, eu quero que traga somente o 'SIM'. A dificuldade é porque é um subselect com case. Eu trago onde? No where ou um having? Como seria mais ou menos

**Resultado Atual**

> ```
> Cliente Integrado
> Sim
> Não
> ```

**Resultado Esperado**

> ```
> Sim
> ```

**Consulta**

```
SELECT distinct 
       (select CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f2.contaid) > 1 THEN 'SIM' ELSE 'NÃO' END as Cliente_Integrado from FRM_51 f2 where f2.C02 = erp.EmpresaERP and (f2.C05 = 3641 or f2.C06 = 3643)) Cliente_Integrado
FROM Tarefa T
LEFT JOIN FRM_52 FRM52 ON FRM52.TarefaID = T.TarID
--LEFT JOIN FRM_51 FRM51 ON FRM51.C01 = FRM52.C01
LEFT JOIN ERPAuxiliar ERP ON ERP.ERPEmpresaERP = FRM52.C01
WHERE T.ProID = 13 
      AND T.TarTipID = 667 --AND CIR.UsuNome LIKE '%FARMACIA%NACIONAL%'
      AND T.TarTitulo NOT IN ('Integração ERP Parceiro','Integração ERP Parceiro - Retorno','Integração ERP Parceiro - Remessa','Envio de Layout - Integração ERP Parceiro')
      and t.TarID not in(163388)
```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de conseguir o resultado que você espera é utilizar a `query` acima dentro de uma `subquery` no `FROM` e aplicar o filtro após isso. Substituindo ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT CASE
                                  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f2.contaid) > 1 THEN 'SIM'
                                  ELSE 'NÃO'
                                END AS Cliente_Integrado
                           FROM frm_51 f2
                          WHERE f2.c02 = erp.empresaerp
                            AND (f2.c05 = 3641 OR f2.c06 = 3643)) AS Cliente_Integrado
          FROM tarefa t
          LEFT JOIN frm_52 frm52 ON frm52.tarefaid = t.tarid
          LEFT JOIN erpauxiliar erp ON erp.erpempresaerp = frm52.c01
         WHERE t.proid = 13
           AND t.tartipid = 667
           AND t.tartitulo NOT IN ('Integração ERP Parceiro',
                                   'Integração ERP Parceiro - Retorno',
                                   'Integração ERP Parceiro - Remessa',
                                   'Envio de Layout - Integração ERP Parceiro')
           AND t.tarid NOT IN (163388)
       ) x
 WHERE x.Cliente_Integrado = 'SIM'
```